# How use navigation event to reload in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have homeScreen , this screen has useEffect and data filteration has in it.
HomeScreen to profilescreen and data update in profile screen and return to homescreen.
this updated data need to show in homescreen.
I want to know is can navigation event focus reload this homescreen?
How can make this

```
 useEffect(()=>{

     let unsub;

     const fetchCard = async ()=>{
            
      // // user
           const uRef = query(doc(db,'users',user.uid))
           const udata = await getDoc(uRef)
          .then((snapshot)=>snapshot.data())

      //     console.log(udata.age)
         
      // //users

      //     const usRef = query(collection(db,'users'))
      //     const usdata =await getDocs(usRef)
      //     .then((snapshot)=>snapshot.docs.map(doc=>({
      //       id:doc.id,
      //       ...doc.data()
      //     })))

      //     console.log(usdata[0].age)


      const swipeRef = collection(db,'users',user.uid,'swipes')
      const myswipeid = await getDocs(swipeRef)
      .then((snapshot)=>snapshot.docs.map(doc=>doc.id))
      
     
      const swipeuserId = myswipeid.length>0?myswipeid :['test'];
     
 
  
      unsub = onSnapshot(query(collection(db,'users'),where('gender','==',udata.interestIn),where("id","not-in",[...swipeuserId])),
            snapshot=>{
                    setProfiles(
                      snapshot.docs
                     
                      .map(doc=>({
                        id :doc.id,
                        ...doc.data()
                      })
                     
                     )
                    )
                  }
      )
     }
     fetchCard()
     return unsub
  },[setProfiles])
```

how can reload this useEffect by navigation back.
can someone show me example

Answer (score 0):

If you using react native navigation then use **useFocusEffect**
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/
this hook call when you come back to the screen(when the current screen is visible or focused)

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

useFocusEffect(()=>{

 let unsub;

 const fetchCard = async ()=>{
        
  // // user
       const uRef = query(doc(db,'users',user.uid))
       const udata = await getDoc(uRef)
      .then((snapshot)=>snapshot.data())

  //     console.log(udata.age)
     
  // //users

  //     const usRef = query(collection(db,'users'))
  //     const usdata =await getDocs(usRef)
  //     .then((snapshot)=>snapshot.docs.map(doc=>({
  //       id:doc.id,
  //       ...doc.data()
  //     })))

  //     console.log(usdata[0].age)


  const swipeRef = collection(db,'users',user.uid,'swipes')
  const myswipeid = await getDocs(swipeRef)
  .then((snapshot)=>snapshot.docs.map(doc=>doc.id))
  
 
  const swipeuserId = myswipeid.length>0?myswipeid :['test'];
 


  unsub = onSnapshot(query(collection(db,'users'),where('gender','==',udata.interestIn),where("id","not-in",[...swipeuserId])),
        snapshot=>{
                setProfiles(
                  snapshot.docs
                 
                  .map(doc=>({
                    id :doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()
                  })
                 
                 )
                )
              }
  )
 }
 fetchCard()
 return unsub
```

},[])

Comment: can you show me example with my code,